# Vim: E212: Cannot open file for writing With SU privilages

Tags: vim

I've been trying to add a MondogDB repo on fedora using vim, but when I run this command:

```
sudo vim etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```

and add this to the file:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

However when I try to save and exit, All I am shown is:

```
"etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo" E212: Cannot open file for writing
```

I've never really used vim before so any help would be appreciated 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Use `$ sudo -e etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo`.

Comment: Make sure your in root Happend to me with vim /etc/yum.repos.d/sever.repo
Cuz iwas in other user account

Answer (score 0):

The file could be set with immutable attribute. To solve that execute:

```
$ sudo chattr -i etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```